# How does Perforce ignore file syntax differ from gitignore syntax?

Tags: git, perforce, gitignore, ignore

What fraction of .gitignore file syntax Perforce was able to implement?

The Perforce documentation for P4IGNORE shows basic ignores and un-ignores with patterns: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/env.P4IGNORE.html

As best I can tell, Perforce does not support:

```
# Ignore file.txt, but not subdir/file.txt
/file.txt

# Ignore directories named foo, but not files named foo
foo/
```

Are there any other differences in the ignore file processing?

Comment: This is out of date for the most recent Perforce release. As far as I can tell,  Perforce now fully supports .gitignore syntax.

Comment: Although the article says "Git ignore syntax is fully supported", I am fairly certain that the git single character wildcard, for patterns like ?, ??, is still not supported.  See http://blog.andy.glew.ca/2016/09/perforce-git-ignore-syntax-is-fully.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the two you listed I've seen that wildcards won't match against directories, only files.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar question and then found this [article](https://www.perforce.com/blog/151203/p4ignore-ignorance-bliss) where I learned that Perforce does accept .gitignore files.

> In fact, you can specify more than one filename in P4IGNORE. In reality, my P4IGNORE looks like this (this is a new feature in 2015.2):
>
> `P4IGNORE=$home/.p4ignore;.gitignore;.p4ignore;`

Comment: Although the article says "Git ignore syntax is fully supported", I m fairly certaion that the git single character wildcard, for patterns like ?, ??, is still not supported.

Answer (score 4):

Also, as far as I can tell (the P4IGNORE mechanism is incompletely documented):

P4IGNORE seems to have no way to escape # (the hash sign, a character that I *really* want to have in P4IGNORE since EMACS creates backup files named #filename#.

It looks like # in P4IGNORE is a comment character, but only if the first character on a line.

So

```
*#*
```

seems to ignore all files with # in them.
i.e. it seems to be the equivalent of Perl regexp qr{^.*#.*$}.

This is a bit scary, since if # was the normal comment character in most systems, the pattern *#* would be a * followed by a comment #*, and would ignore all files.  But it seems to work.

(Git's handling of # is a bit special as well.)

P4IGNORE does not seem to handle patterns such as

```
# matches any single character filename    
?
```

a single character

```
[seq]
```

matches any character in set

etc.,

so to ignore a filename with a single letter like 'a', I had to list all 62 possibilities [a-zA-Z0-9].  (I have a habit of creating tmp files like 'a', 'b' ...).

I have not yet grokked Perforce's handling of periods in filenames.
I know for sure that to ignore a filename like '.#more-crap'
you have to do

```
.#*
```

in addition to

```
*#*
```

but this may just be normal dot file hiding.

However, there have been several cases where a pattern like

```
tmp-*
```

was not catching 'tmp-foo.txt'

that I fixed by adding

```
tmp-*.*
```

(Note: most recently I have been using bzr and hg, with fully powerful regexps, so may be looking for stuff more powerful than git provides)